# Understanding of arrow functions es6

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, lexical, arrow-functions

I'm trying to understand es6's new arrow function syntax and how it relates to what I already know.

My understanding is arrow functions have

- No name
- No arguments object
- No ability of being a generator
- Lexical this

So is the following notion correct as long as you are not using the arguments object thinking it is for the arrow and not using the arrow as a generator

```
function () {}.bind(this); // synonym for () => {}; given the contraints above ???
```

My main question is. *Am I missing something fundamental about arrow functions?*

Comment: *"No ability of being an iterator"* What does that mean? Functions are never iterators. Did you mean constructor?

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry I meant generator. I'll update the question.

Comment: What do you mean they have no name? You can do something like: `f = (a,b,c) => a + b +c`

Comment: @Cristy I mean the function itself is an unnamed function. f is an identifier that references the arrow. f is not the *name* of the arrow.

Comment: Yes, but the arrow function is by definition a shorthand for an `anonymous` **function**. What is your question? What "are you missing" ?

Comment: @Cristy I am asking if I am missing any caveats to how arrows work. Also is my example an accurate representation in es5 with the constraints above?

Comment: @t3dodson You can read specs or other description of the arrow function, such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @t3dodson If that's your question then no. You also cannot `new` an arrow function. In ES6 that would throw an error.

Comment: Not that it's a common case, but functions, being objects, can certainly have iteration protocol defined on them. let  g = x => x+1; g[Symbol.iterator] = function* (){ var i = yield g(0); yield 2; yield "weird"; }; for (y of g){console.log(y)}; //=> logs: 1,2,"weird"  You just can't define the generator function itself as an arrow function.

Answer (score 2):

That's basically correct, but it's probably too confusing to say that Arrow functions have "no" arguments object, as that might imply that it'd be undefined.  What they don't do is *redefine* that keyword within themselves or for themselves, so it stays defined as whatever it already was in the lexical scope:

```
(function test(){
   let test2 = () => console.log(this,arguments);
   test2();
}).bind({heya:true})(4,5);
```

That'll log: "{heya: true}, [4, 5]";  Why?  Because the arguments object and the this context simply *stay* the same inside the body of the Arrow function: the outer/lexical context is unaltered.

Also, while the Arrow function itself doesn't have a name in the sense of function.name being defined, you can certainly assign it to a name and then use that name within the body of the arrow function, as with this currying function:

```
var curry = (f, ...args) => {
  if (f.length <= args.length){
    return f(...args);
  }
  return (...more) => curry(f, ...args, ...more);
};
```